# How to serialize Objectify Entities with Ref<> attributes

Tags: objectify

I have the following entity

```
class Student {
  String name;
  Ref<Course> course;

  public Course getCourse() { return course.get() }
}
```

I am trying to serialize the Student and put it in my custom Memcache. Serializing an entity with ref causes it to turn into [dead ref](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Entities#additional-ref-considerations). When i get the entity back from memcache How do i make sure that it fetches the recent data back from datastore.

TLDR: I am trying to serialize an deserialize objectify entity with Ref<> attribute. After i have deserialized them how to i ensure that the ref loads the value again from datastore? I dont want to clear the session cache for all entities.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `Key<?>` instead? Then just load the keys as necessary instead of `Ref.get()`.

`Ref`'s serialization behavior is to actually serialize an object graph - for example, if you wanted to send a whole graph across the wire. It's not clear that this was the right choice, and maybe it's time to eliminate the `DeadRef` in v6. Thoughts?